# Converting JSON to CSV with array objects in JSON Python

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a JSON with mostly simple key, value pairs. But some of thema are arrays. I want to convert the json to a simple csv format in order to import the values into tables of my postgresql database. The JSON file looks like this

```json
{  
    "name": "Text",
    "operator_type": [
        "one",
        "two",
        "three"
    ],

    "street": "M\u00f6nchhaldenstra\u00dfe ",
    "street_nr": "113",
    "zipcode": "70191",
    "city": "Stuttgart",

    "operator_type_id": [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3"
    ],
    "dc_operator_per": [
        "100",
        "",
        ""
    ],
        
    "input_power": 600.0,
    "el_power": 800.0,
    "col_power": 300.0

}
```

To convert im using this simple method:

```py
import pandas as pd

data=pd.read_json('export.json')

data.to_csv('text.csv')

data=pd.read_csv('text.csv')
```

But for each of my array elements it creates a new line in the csv with the same values if it is not an array. Like this:

```
name,dc_operator_type,capacity_kwh,export_me
Test,Colocation,,600,True
Test,,,600,True,
```

I want to have it like this:

```
name,dc_operator_type,capacity_kwh,export_me
Test,Colocation,,600,True
```

Or one object has two operator_types, then like this:

```
name,dc_operator_type,capacity_kwh,export_me
Test,Colocation,,600,True
,Seconlocation,,,
```

Comment: You didn't specify what you want to do with the arrays. What would be the expected CSV generated from this JSON? Also, please avoid posting images, especially for CSVs that are basically text files (try to open it with a text editor for seeing what's inside).

Comment: I added the csv differntly now. I want to use the csv in the add to add it to my postgresql database by using python. I was not successfull to import it directly to the fields in my database so I  thought trying with csv will work. And because one Object can have more values for operator type I want to write them in new line

Comment: Your `JSON` data doesn't match the csv data you want and can't give you advice